# Array of objects to 3 dimensions

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I got an api response from the server that return data in big array, that contain every data in object.
Looks something like that:

```
Data = [
   {id:0, name: "name"},
   {id:1, name: "name"},
   {id:2, name: "name"},
   {id:3, name: "name"},
   {id:4, name: "name"}
   .......
]
```

And I'm trying to check every 3 objects and insert them into array. That will look like 3 dimensions.

Something like this:

```
 Data = [
   [{id:0, name: "name"},
   {id:1, name: "name"},
   {id:2, name: "name"}]
   [{id:3, name: "name"},
   {id:4, name: "name"},
   {id:5, name: "name"}]
   .......
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
const data = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "name"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "name"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "name"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "name"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "name"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "name"
  }
]
const output = [];
let i = 0;
while(data[i]) {
  output.push(data.slice(i, i + 3))
  i += 3;
}
console.log(output);
```